# Which control to use for either or values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my iOS puzzle app, the user can pick between 30 second and 60 second duration. Right now, I'm using a UISlider control to achieve that. Should I be using a segmented control or a stepper control?

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user cannot pick anything in between 30 and 60, then the segmented control

```
[ 30 | 60 ]
```

is the most appropriate choice.

If the user can pick from a contiguous range, a slider is a better choice.

```
48 -------------O------
```

If the values are not contiguous, say, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, and 60, then the stepper and a label may be more appropriate, although a slider with a label would work as well.

```
40 [-|+]
```

You should also take into consideration the amount of real estate the controls are going to take: in general, sliders need more horizontal space than steppers and segmented controls.

Comment: Excellent replies with diagrams

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a segmented control. Since it's between two different options, it would probably be the best bet. This way you have a clear view of what's selected. You  may set the wrong expectations if you use either a slider or stepper, a slider usually lets you select a range of values, as does a stepper.